# How was the opening scene with the fly made?

Tags: film-techniques, production, once-upon-a-time-in-the-west

This may sound like a bit of an odd question, but I was wondering how the opening scene in *Once Upon A Time in The West* was made and more specifically, how they made the fly do what it did. It must not have been easy to get a fly to fly to his beard and stay there despite all of his attempts to get rid of it. So how did they make this fly do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The scene with Jack Elam and the fly was first attempted by placing a fake fly on the actor's face. When that didn't work, better results were achieved by smearing honey or jam on Elam's beard to attract flies kept in a jar just out of view and released one at a time.
>
> Source:  *[Jack Elam and the Fly in Once Upon a Time in the West](http://pov.imv.au.dk/Issue_24/section_1/artc4A.html)* by Richard Raskin